# Add a "Connect a cloud service" option to Word on iPhone & iPad

Tags: ios, cloud, ms-office, office-addins

Microsoft Office applications on iOS can open documents from a cloud service, such as OneDrive, Dropbox, iCloud, SharePoint, etc:

[image]   [image]

In the Windows desktop version of Microsoft Office you can [add your own options to this list](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/add-dropbox-to-office-2013) using registry keys.

Can I add my options to cloud services list in case of iOS? I guess I need to develop MS Office add-in to do this, but what type of add-in it should be?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?